API FOR JS loop giving undefined at end of data
I am working with this Github code. https://github.com/He3556/Mixcloud-Unfollowers
the issue I am facing is that it seems that at the end of the API page, the for loop gives me undefined on the username variable. Ive tried a few fixes but none have worked. here is the loop (please note, varables are declared at the start of the js file, not shown here)
// Get the JSON object - with number of followers and number of following +++++++++++++++++++++++++
$.getJSON('https://api.mixcloud.com/' + uname + '/?metadata=1', function (result) {

            // +++++ Get metadata from Mixloud
            var tfo = (result.follower_count);
            followercnt = parseInt(tfo);
            followingcnt = (result.following_count);

            // Show data
            $("#info").append('Followers:' + followercnt + ' <br />Following:' + followingcnt + '');

            // how often get 100x followers
            if (followercnt == "0") {
                $("#error").append('User was not found on Mixcloud<br /><br /><br /><br />');}
            var tempcnt = (followercnt / 100);
            var cnt = Math.ceil(tempcnt);

            // how often get 100x following
            if (followingcnt == "0") {
            $("#error").append('User was not found on Mixcloud<br /><br /><br /><br />'); }
            var tempcntb = (followingcnt / 100);
            var cntb = Math.ceil(tempcntb);


// ************* START *************
// 1 - get list of followers
getfolls(cnt, uname);

// 2 - get list of ppl you follow
getfollowing(cntb, uname);

});


// Get list of followers +++++++++++++++++++++++++
function getfolls(cnt, uname) {

                  for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
                          $.getJSON('https://api.mixcloud.com/' + uname + '/followers/?limit=' + lmt + '&offset=' + offst + '', function (result) {
                           //     console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                                  // +++++ Get 100 packs of followers in the array
                                   var temp = '';
                                    var username = '';
                                   for (var r = 0; r < 100; r++) {
                                     var temp = (result.data[r].username);
                                     if (username == undefined) {
                                        console.log("there was an undefined user!");
                                     }
                                     follers[j] = temp;
                                     j++;
                                     $("#cntfollowers").text('Followers:' + j + ' ');
                                     console.log("temp followers: " + temp);
                               };
                             });
                  offst = (offst + 100);
                 };
  return follers
}


The undefined happens it seems at the end of every page from the API. its not a co-incidence I dont think, however, the rest of the code executes before this can continue and therefore my lists are incomplete. Please help, much appreciated.

Bit confused with this loop: for (var r = 0; r < 100; r++). Wouldn't the last page of your response contain anywhere between 0 and 100 records?

Yes I can't see why it's a problem either. That's why I posted it here.

What I mean is, this loop is probably causing the error. If you have less than 100 records in the last response then this will throw an error.

yeah i got there in the end, thank you! using a .each and key values sorted it out. the overall code is pants tho. not impressed.
